# Can't write JPEG image to HDD using AVFoundation

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, avfoundation, core-image

I'm using `AVFoundation` module for accessing a FaceTime camera on macOS 10.13.3.

`captureSession.startRunning()` method is running, camera's indicator is green. But I can't capture and write JPEG image on my hard drive. What's wrong with my code?

I need an output `JPG` image `167`x`188` pixels (width x height).

I'm working in Xcode 9, Swift 4.

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation
import CoreImage

class ViewController: NSViewController, 
                      AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var camera: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var captureButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: NSButton!

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var imageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
    
        camera.layer = CALayer()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.low
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
   
        for device in devices {
            print(device)
         
            if ((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaType.video)) {
                print(device)
                captureDevice = device 
            }
        }
    
        if captureDevice != nil {
            do {
                try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!))
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer?.frame = (self.camera.layer?.frame)!
                self.camera.layer?.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

                captureSession.startRunning()
            
            } catch {
                print(AVCaptureSessionErrorKey.description)
            }
        }
    }

    var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter!
    var imageWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    let outputSettings = [String: Any]()
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/catalyst/Desktop/image.jpg")

    @IBAction func captureImage(_ sender: NSButton) {
        print("Taking photo...")
    
        imageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        imageOutput?.outputSettings = [
                       AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg,
                       AVVideoWidthKey: NSNumber(value: Float(167)),
                      AVVideoHeightKey: NSNumber(value: Float(188))
        ] as [String : Any]
    
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(imageOutput!) {
            captureSession.addOutput(imageOutput!)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func saveImage(_ sender: NSButton) {
        print("Saving photo...")
    
        let writerFileName = url
    
        assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: writerFileName, 
                                          fileType: AVFileType.jpg)
        imageWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, 
                                         outputSettings: outputSettings)
    
        assetWriter.add(imageWriterInput)
    }
}
```

There's no compiler's errors and there's no captured image on my Desktop.

[image]

Comment: Not hard-coding a file path will be a good start.

Comment: You're supposed to use `URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/swift/Desktop/")`

Comment: @andy, was trying to solve your problem and just realized today that my Mac's webcam has stopped working all together, I wasn't getting it returned in `devices()` call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An edit has changed this question's character completely, so here is the

**NEW ANSWER**

This captures an image for me. Make sure sandboxing isn't stopping you from writing to path you indicate. `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` doesn't seem to resize for you, so you can resize using something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991610/22147).

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
    if captureDevice != nil {
        do {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!))

            // AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer code
            // assumes you have camera NSView
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer!.frame = (self.camera.layer?.frame)!
            self.camera.layer?.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            captureSession.startRunning()

        } catch {
            print(AVCaptureSessionErrorKey.description)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func captureImage(_ sender: NSButton) {
    print("Taking photo...")
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(with: .video) {
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection) { jpegBuffer, error in
            // TODO: check error here

            if let data = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(jpegBuffer!) {
                // make sure sandboxing isn't blocking this path                
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/swift/Desktop/picture.jpg")

                // resize here using something like
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991610/22147

                try! data.write(to: url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Your url references a directory. Try referencing a file:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/swift/Desktop/movie.mov")
```

You also need to implement the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocol.

`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` is not a file, it's a way of getting a callback with video and audio buffers in real-ish time and that's where you should append samples to `videoWriterInput`.

`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVAssetWriter` are quite low level. If you just want to record to a file, you can replace them with the simpler `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.

Comment: Do you know how to stop recording, not stopping capture session with captureSession.stopRunning() ?

Comment: Just don't write to your `AVAssetWriter` in the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` callback. p.s. that's a new question

Comment: ...and there's still no output file on my hard drive.

Comment: Your code is missing some pieces, see my updated answer.

Comment: You should probably be using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput `

Comment: I decided not to use video capture. I need just output JPEG image. Could you help me with this code? I don't understand where the error is.

Comment: I've got an error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: near this: captureSession.addOutput(imageOutput!)

Comment: You need to add camera to your app’s capabilities. It’s a sandboxing thing

Comment: I wrote "csrutil disable" in Terminal

Comment: My image output is not optional. You’ve copied the code wrong

Comment: I tried making it non-optional (like `var imageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()`), it takes photos but the FaceTime camera screen is black...

Comment: Update your question or link to the non working code

Comment: ah, I showed you how to capture a JPEG image. I left a comment for you to add the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in yourself. Updated the answer to show this too.

Comment: I tried to add `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. Still not working.

Comment: No idea - you could either link to some code to run or go back and modify your working preview to add the capture code I posted

Comment: It works. Great! Thank you very much. I'll award this bounty to you in 4 hours.